# Slack Application Socket Mode with Quartz Scheduling

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, slack-api, quartz, slack-block-kit

Creating a Slack Application in Java using Springboot and Quartz for scheduling.

Scheduler is not executing the job at specified time when the application is using Socket (using socket instead of a public end point to which slack can post requests).

The same method, when invoked without creating the socket, works fine - the scheduler is executing the job at specified time correctly.

The same is the case when hitting our localhost through postman, when socket mode is off it works fine, but when socket mode is on and hitting my localhost url which has GetMapping, it doesn't send back any responses.

So, I think because of running the application in socket mode, quartz scheduler is not executing the job.

Can I get any help regarding this issue?

Tried executing the method without socket mode and with socket mode to verify if the issue is because of that only.